# Prove that any power of $10$ can be written as sum of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, sums-of-squares

I do know various techniques to solve this problem, but I need an elementary solution which can be explained to a fifth grader (that is, with as little algebra as possible, no modulo arithmetic).

Comment: Can the person who vote down this question, explain me why he did it? I just want to know what was wrong, with it.

Comment: There were several minor details wrong with it, but nothing that would compel me to downvote it. This is the closest you are going to get to an answer from the actual downvoter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3^2+1^2=10$, $8^2+6^2=100$, $30^2+10^2=1000$, $80^2+60^2=10000$, $300^2+100^2=100000$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

If $n=2m$ is even, then
$$ 10^n=(10^m)^2+0^2$$
while if $n=2m+1$ is odd, then
$$ 10^n=(9+1)\cdot 10^{2m}=(3\cdot 10^m)^2+(10^m)^2$$