# Perfect squares that ends in $4$s

Tags: arithmetic, square-numbers

1. Prove that there is an infinity of perfect squares which have $4$ as the last **3** digits.
2. Prove that there are no perfect squares which have $4$ as the last **4** digits.

This is a problem form a math contest (Romanian Math Olympiad, county level) for fifth graders. No calculators allowed. I couldn't even come quickly with a solution at highschool level, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: Nothing. This is a problem form a math contest for fifth graders. I can't even come with a solution at highschool level...

Comment: It is highly doubtful that this is a problem geared towards fifth graders.

Comment: @amWhy You probably never seen problems from the Romanian Math Olympiad. This is not even from the last stage.

Comment: Are calculators allowed?

Comment: No calculators allowed

Comment: This isn't that hard.  To do the first part you only need to exhibit a single value (easy enough).  To do the second, well..only the last four digits matter so just write down the equations they'd to satisfy.   It isn't all that bad.

Comment: Actually, easier than I was suggesting.  $10000k+4444=4\times \left(2500k+1111\right)$ and $2500k+1111\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ so it can not be a square.

Comment: @amWhy why you don't find another way to waste people's time? I do prepare a fifth grader for a competition, and it happen that I could not come quickly with a solution. Is not even the first time: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657524/prove-that-any-power-of-10-can-be-written-as-sum-of-two-squares . I think it probably bothers you because you were not able to solve it.

Comment: @motoras I apologize.   But even so, you're not exempt from the expectation for you to know [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and apply it. See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, and http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/.  Just because you're asking for folks to answer a question as though they were answering a 5th grader, doesn't mean you cannot provide the explanation in your question, as you just provided me with, and you are expected to contribute to the solution: what you've thought of, where else you've consulted, etc.

Comment: You've essentially asked two problem statements, both imperatives, and you've ordered us to do what you instruct us to do.  That's rude.

Comment: @amWhy nobody ordered you anything. I was typing from a phone, so I wrote as short as possible.
The question was clear stated so what is the matter?
If you have time and know the answer, I'll appreciate your effort.
If you can't help or don't want to, what is the point on trying to prove that I am an idiot  (as you did in the comment I flag) or to lecture me a about forum etiquette.
Spent your  time in some more useful endeavors.
Also there is no always time to try a solution of your own, so checking quick if someone has already a solution is a great time saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe that $1444=38^2$, the perfect squares

$$(1000k+38)^2=1000000k^2+76000k+1444$$ end in $444$.

---

For the second question, notice that the last four digits of a perfect square only depend on the last two digits of the root, and we have

$$66^2<4444<67^2.$$

Comment: I'm surprised you couldn't come up with this yourself, @motoras.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick proof for the second part:

Every natural  number which ends in $4444$ is of the form $$10000k+4444=4\times (2500k+1111)$$  for some $k\in \mathbb N$.

Of course, in order for this to be a square, $2500k+1111$ would also have to be a square.

$2500$ is divisible by $4$ and $1111=4\times 277+3$ so $2500k+1111$ is of the form $4l+3$ but it is easy to see that any square is of the form $4l$ or $4l+1$ so we are done.